# mysql delete duplicate rows from table

Tags: mysql, duplicates

i have the following table. I need to remove duplicate rows based on the zip column.

```
id      state       zip
1       CA          112233
2       CA          112233
3       CA          112233
4       CA          113300
.       .           .
.       .           .   
999     FL          345678
1000    FL          234579
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way is to identify the ones you need to keep.... try this

```
DELETE FROM  `you-table`
WHERE
   id not in (
               select *
                  from(
                       SELECT
                          min(t.id) as keepID
                       from
                           `you-table` as t
                       group by concat(t.state,t.zip)
                      ) as keepTable
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of repetitions is low you can  repeat this command  the time you need otherwise you shuold use an iteration

```
delete from yourTable AS a  where a.id in (select max(b.id) from yourTable AS b 
 group by b.zip having count(b.id) >1 );
```

Caution make a copy before try.

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'yourTable ' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I have update the answer

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS a where a.id in (select max(b.id) from MyTable AS b group by b.zip ha' at line 1